# How to add Canon LBP2900b printer to a Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: printing, raspberry-pi4, cups, network-printers

The printer Canon LBP2900b is not listed in the Cups of the Raspberry pi..
I have searched a lot on that but unfortunately haven't found any such working method.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue getting Canon LBP6020 working with cups on pi. Found the *nix driver but no version of armhf so I did not manage to get it to work. Sharing this in case if you are lucky with your model:

Get the driver from https://www.canon.ie/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp2900b.html?type=drivers&language=&os=windows%2010%20(64-bit)

Untar and find the ppd file in Src\cndrvcups-capt-2.71-1\cndrvcups-capt-2.71\ppd

Add it via cups admin when adding the printer

If you are getting the filter related error rastertosfp, then oof! My understanding of this error is you have to install it proper (using the proper ./install.sh script)

Comment: LBP6020 is a UFRII-LT device (`rastertosfp`). CAPT driver architecture is much more complicated, it involves the daemon which communicates with `lp0`, and a special configuration, such as pointing the CUPS backend to CAPT daemon over socket or TCP on localhost. UFRII and UFRII-LT-based devices don't require that, they just work in qemu-i386-userspace without additional configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There's open source [captdriver](https://github.com/mounaiban/captdriver) for Canon LBP2900. It works on Raspberry Pi.

The alternative way is to use official Canon CAPT driver (cndrvcups-capt) for x86, emulated with qemu-i386-userspace or box86.
With box86, the processing time is about 4-5 seconds on [Cortex-A7 @ 1 GHz](https://printserver.ink/), which is pretty reasonable.